# Fixing messy commit history in Git

Tags: git, github, version-control

I made some changes and then committed and pushed them on GitHub.

However, in my second commit, I realized I didn't need some of the code that I pushed in the first commit. I deleted it and pushed it again.

But now, the commit history is pretty messy (one commit adds some code in a file, next commit removes it).

- Would I be able to fix this if I just squash it together (will it just ignore the code that was added and then deleted)?
- If I reset it back to the original state and commit my final changes again, how exactly would this be reflected on GitHub once I push the branch?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to just squash it with an interactive rebase (see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History)

Whether you do this or reset to the original state and then add a commit containing only your final changes, to get this state on GitHub, you will need to force push, as the remote repository will have a different history to yours. If you are collaborating with others, you may want to use the --force-with-lease option to make sure noone has pushed since your last push. After a force push, the remote branch should look identical to your local copy.

Comment: By my second question, I meant what will the commit history look like, then? I know that if I choose to revert back to an older version, it introduces "revert commits". Does something similar happen if I go by any of the two ways you mentioned?

Comment: In that case, I misunderstood. My interpretation of reverting was simply checking out an older commit and working from there. That can create orphaned/dangling commits, but those don't show up in your commit history, making it rather clean.